# Hand-bone scanner biometrics

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, anatomy

Instead of scanning a user's fingerprint or palm-print to enter my secret lair, I want to scan the sizes and shapes of the bones in their hand. This way people can wear gloves, be dirty, injure their skin, etc. and still be able to quickly open doors without the pesky implanting of RFID tags or handing out security badges which can be stolen.

Questions:

- Are the sizes and shapes of hand-bones unique enough to be secure?
- Are there any existing systems which scan hand-bones instead of hand prints?
- What type of technology could do this? Would I need an X-ray system or is skin-penetrating radar possible?

Comment: The major problem is that the bones of the hand (as all bones) are plastic; they change shape and density during life. Any such system will need to allow for quite a lot of variation in order to keep the number of false negatives low enough; which will then increase the rate of false positives. And I would *definitely* not want to absorb a dose of X-rays every time I want to unlock my phone, thank you. (For an introduction of how less intrusive scanning is done by the powers that be, see [full body scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_body_scanner).) (Humans are transparent to radar.)

Comment: Ah, and the problem of dirty hands etc. is very nicely solved by iris scanners, retina scanners, or by those newfangled [finger vein scanners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_vein_recognition).

Comment: @AlexP While bones do change over time, it wouldn't be difficult to simply slightly update the scanner's model of the user each time they scan themselves. This way, it keeps up with growth and change.

Comment: @AlexP Also, similarly to how gloves thwart hand scanners, sunglasses, combat helmets, and visors thwart iris scanners or at least make them slow. I'm looking for something that is *fast*, like barely-need-to-break-stride fast when going through a door.

Comment: Getting a dose of X-rays daily is not conducive to a long a healthy life... (And what about voice recognition, or gait recognition? You want something which is minimally invasive.) (Plus X-rays can be trivially faked.)

Comment: I wouldn't ignore @AlexP's issue about bones changing over time. There would be a limit to the maximum time between scans that any software could permit without becoming useless. The longer you allow, the easier it would be that someone else's bones could be interpreted as valid. Assuming only adults over the age of 25, I'd be hard pressed to believe more than 1-2 years could go by between scans.

Comment: @JBH Of course, but in my use case, individuals scan at least once per day, if not multiple times per day.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want such an expensive tech when [biometric gait analysis](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21528835-600-cameras-know-you-by-your-walk/) is already starting to become viable? No X-rays. No skin-penetrating radar. Just cameras watching you as you walk toward the door. It's not that hard to correlate gait through dresses, trench coats, etc. An an argument against it for something like a broken leg is as applicable to a broken finger bone. The answer to your question is probably "yes, but there are easier ways."

Comment: As far as I remember we have a number of things that are exclusive to each person, and I don't remember the shape of your hand bones being one of them (we have more reliable bones to use in identification, like the skull). Plus running an x-ray through your hand every time you go through a door is not healthy (why the "x-ray doctor" memes exist). Instead, [there are much easier things to use which can be just as fast and much more reliable](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20170109-the-seven-ways-you-are-totally-unique) (as well as healthier) to identify your users.

Comment: hand bone shape can change remarkably fast, learning a new skill skill that is heavy on hand use and in a few weeks your code is invalid. things like martial arts, boxing, handgun proficiency, smiting, rock climbing, wood working, not terribly rare skills. your bones are constantly changing so they don't make very good metrics anyway.

Comment: If you want a bone that does not change much use teeth, most of the same problems but  at least those changes are either predictable or very noticeable by the person. teeth are not constantly being reabsorbed and redeposited by the body.

Answer (score 2):

**Are the sizes and shapes of hand-bones unique enough to be secure?**

Yes but they change over time. People would need to use it all the time. Hand injuries, growth, osteoporosis or arthritis could affect the scan and lock people out.

Next you need to look at the security of biometrics in general. The inherent flaw in biometrics is that they can't be changed. A password is more secure because you can change it if someone steals it. If someone steals an xray of your hand and 3d prints fake bones and sets them in a silicone hand, you can't lock them out anymore.

**Are there any existing systems which scan hand-bones instead of hand prints?**

Not that I can see. Palm prints and fingerprints are easier to get than scanning bones and more than adequate.

**What type of technology could do this? Would I need an X-ray system or is skin-penetrating radar possible?**

[Ultrasound](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/245491) would be safest.

Comment: *"If someone steals an xray of your hand and 3d prints fake bones and sets them in a silicone hand, you can't lock them out anymore."* Yes you can. Cut that hand off and get a custom made prosthetic one ;)

Comment: Over time in this case being withing weeks if exercised, bone is constantly being broken down and redeposited so it can change shape remarkably fast.